# Understanding Reactjs rendering and event handling. A simple Button toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a novice, so please have mercy with me ;-). I have the following runnable code snippet example:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selected = false;
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.selected = true;
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.selected.toString()}</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This should render the Button text from 'false' to 'true', when the Button is clicked. But it doesn't. Could someone explain to me, what a working example looks like?

Comment: You're just using `this` to try and refer to the component's properties, you should be using React's state mechanism. So in the constructor `this.state={selected:false}` then in handleClick `this.setState({selected:!this.state.selected});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why you dont use state with your example, but this would help.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: false
    }

   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 handleClick() {
  this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
 }

 render(){
  return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.selected}</button>;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal variables don't rerender the component. You need to maintain a component `state`. Whenever you change the `state` by `setState` function, the component will re-render and the changes will be reflected on the page.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selected: false};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    // Always use setState to set the state
    this.setState({selected: true});
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.selected.toString()}</button>;
  }
}
```